# Java send class parameters by only one object

Tags: java

It is possible to create an Object as "only for parameters"?. For example:

```java
class MyClass {
    public String a;
    public Number b;

    public MyClass(Object params) {
        this.a = params.a !== null ? params.a : "default";
        this.b = params.b !== null ? params.b : 0;
    }
}

void main() {
    MyClass myclass1 = new MyClass(new Object() {
        String a = "hey";
    });

    MyClass myclass2 = new MyClass(new Object() {
        Number b = 123;
    });

    MyClass myclass3 = new MyClass(new Object() {
        String a = "!!!";
        Number b = 5;
    });
}
```

Obviously this code doesn't work, I tried a lot of ways trying to replicate it, maybe with Templates (Generic)?

The expected results will be:

```
myclass1.a == "hey";
myclass1.b == 0;

myclass2.a == "default";
myclass2.b == 123;

myclass3.a == "!!!";
myclass3.b == 5;
```

Comment: Idk but what about using HashMap?

Comment: I suggest you create a List<Object> and pass any parameter to your constructor. Then, populate your list with the parameters you have.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to create required instance:

```
public final class MyClass {

    private final String str;
    private final Number number;

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    private MyClass(Builder builder) {
        str = builder.str;
        number = builder.number;
    }

    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }

    public Number getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public static final class Builder {

        private String str = "default";
        private Number number = 0;

        private Builder() {
        }

        public MyClass build() {
            return new MyClass(this);
        }

        public Builder str(String str) {
            this.str = str;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder number(Number number) {
            this.number = number;
            return this;
        }

    }
}
```

---

**Demo:**

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    MyClass myclass1 = MyClass.builder().str("hey").build();
    MyClass myclass2 = MyClass.builder().number(123).build();
    MyClass myclass3 = MyClass.builder().str("!!!").number(5).build();
}
```

---

In case you do not want to use [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), you could use class override:

```
public class MyClass {

    public String getStr() {
        return "default";
    }

    public Number getNumber() {
        return 0;
    }

}

public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    MyClass myclass1 = new MyClass() {
        @Override
        public String getStr() {
            return "hey";
        }
    };

    MyClass myclass2 = new MyClass() {
        @Override
        public String getStr() {
            return "hey";
        }

        @Override
        public Number getNumber() {
            return 123;
        }
    };

    MyClass myclass3 = new MyClass() {
        @Override
        public String getStr() {
            return "!!!";
        }

        @Override
        public Number getNumber() {
            return 5;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I think the author is asking to add parameters as needed to a single instance of the class, and not to multiple instances per multiple parameters. That is, to add 1 parameter or 10 parameters to the same class when instantiated.